# Putting App Resources in Document Directory in iOS

Tags: ios, resources, directory, document

My app have too much dynamic app resources like images, html+css and xml or json files..that can be updated, So I cannot put these resources in app bundle it will not get updated once on app store i need to have it updated there...secondly i also cannot put these resources on server where I can request the content from server every time i need it...

So my question is that is good to store data locally in document directory??? how does apple app review team will react to it? I have heard that there is an iCloud problem while putting data in document directory is it right?

So where to store data of iOS application locally on device?

Thanks in Advance.... Looking for some good solid answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of data should be copied to `~/Library/Application Support`. See the [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for full details on where everything goes and how it will be treated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider having the initial assets you are referring to be resident in your application bundle. And then when you have updated versions, save them in your Documents directory (or any legal path you want).

The reason for this is for failover, in case there is a problem, it allows you to revert back. When you are dynamically loading content, you have to factor in you can encounter various problems during a download such as corrupt data or even a dependency not being downloaded yet.

FWIW, I implemented this for a game that supported dynamic loading of content. The bundle had the original assets. There was a temp download directory. When data was validated, it was moved to a locale where it was consumable. On app start, the first step was to just copy the data from the bundle to the consumable directory. While it seems perhaps wasteful and several steps, it worked surprising well and most would not even know this sort of thing was happening.